# Adding Chained CA certificate on /etc/ssl/certinfo.ldif file

Tags: ldap, openldap, self-signed-certificate

I have been created following files for my LDAP server using certtool.
1.root.pem
2.ldap_crt.pem
3.ldap_key.pem

Above created files has been configured in the /etc/ssl/certinfo.ldif file like mentioned below.

```
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/root.pem
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/ldap_crt.pem
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/ldap_key.pem
```

As of this everything is working fine for me with ssl and startTLS.

Now I have created intermediate CA file.

**Question 1 - Could any one help me here for configuring the intermediate CA in to /etc/ssl/certinfo.ldif file.**

**Question 2 - Do we need to add specific entry for root CA as well as intermediate CA or any one of the CA certificate itself is fine.**

Answer (score 0):

OpenLDAP does not have a separate configuration parameter for specifying intermediate CA certificate(s).

You either append the chain to the file referenced by *olcTLSCertificateFile* or prepend it to the file referenced by *olcTLSCACertificateFile*.